# I don't understand the Syntax Error: can't assign to operator

Tags: python-3.x

```
complete_weather=open('complete_weather_filename.csv','r')
cleaned_weather=open('cleaned_weather_filename.csv','w')
for i in complete_weather:
    scw=i.split(',')
    writing_stuff=scw[0]+scw[1]+scw[2]+scw[3]+scw[8], sep=',', end='\n'
    cleaned_weather.write(writing_stuff)
```

I've been getting that the write_stuff has "Syntax Error: can't assign to operator". Can someone explain the logic behind that? To me this should work.

Comment: `sep` and `end` only work with the `print` function.

Comment: thank you i got it that makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

At one point you had a call to `print()`. The call itself was removed, but the optional arguments it took weren't. Remove them.